# Is there a multi images to 1 image deep learning method? (pix2pix?)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to build a video stabilization deep learning model.
I want to make the model predict how the frame should be stabilized depending on the last 10 frames

I have tried **pix2pix**, which is image to image, but I didn't get a good result
so, I want the same as pix2pix but **multi images to 1 image**
is there a method or can I do it using pix2pix?

Answer (score 1):

So, I do not know if you actually need to build this video stabilization using deep learning or if you just want on off-the-shelves solution.

For the on-the-shelves solution, you can look into vidgear that has an awesome stabilisation system built-in: https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/stabilizer/overview/

If you want a more advanced solution and architecture, you could take a look at his thread of paper with code: https://paperswithcode.com/task/video-stabilization

Given the current architecture of pix2pix, I do not see how multi-images will provide some stabilisation since, it is just as you said, pix2pix does not consider its previous output nor the flow of images to generate its prediction.

I hope that it helps ^^

Comment: I think it's possible, look at this reprository https://github.com/NVIDIA/vid2vid ,
it's based on pix2pixHD, it could be possible if there is multi images to 1 image way.

Comment: Oh, that is for sure. However, vid2vid is based on pix2pix but adds an other level of control to have a coherency between the frames. If you can leverage the architecture used in this repo, you might do a video stabilisation software. Although I do not quite know how you would do it given vid2vid output.

Please keep me posted on this one, I am curious ^^